# Flutter - How to make a variable accessible to a child widget

Tags: flutter

i've created a StatelessWidget named FirestoreStreamBuilder that create a Stream and return a child.

```
class FirestoreStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

  FirestoreStreamBuilder({@required this.collectionReference, @required this.child, @required this.noDataChild});

  final String collectionReference;
  final Widget child;
  final Widget noDataChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection(collectionReference).snapshots() ,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return noDataChild;
        return child;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I need to make `snapshot` accessible from `child`. How can i do that?

Example:

```
FirestoreStreamBuilder(
          collectionReference: 'collection',
          child: Text('I want to acces to snapshot here $snapshot'), //How can I access snapshot from here?
          noDataChild: Container(),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create custom callback**

```
typedef OnDataReceived = void Function(DocumentSnapShot);//or your return type

    class FirestoreStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

      FirestoreStreamBuilder({@required this.collectionReference, @required this.child, 
      @required this.noDataChild, @required this.onDataReceived});

      final String collectionReference;
      final Widget child;
      final Widget noDataChild;
      final OnDataReceived onDataReceived;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection(collectionReference).snapshots() ,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                 onDataReceived(snapshot);
                 return noDataChild;
            }
            return child;
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

**Access snapshot in widget**

```
FirestoreStreamBuilder(
      collectionReference: 'collection',
      child: Text('Hurray you got snapshot !'),
      noDataChild: Container(),
      onDataReceived:(snapshot){
         //TODO your task with snapshot
     }
    )
```

Comment: I'm sorry because i'm a beginner. I still have the same question: How can i make `snapshot` accesible from the widget placed in `child:`? Because now, i can make tasks inside `onDataReceived`, but i want to use `snapshot` inside child Widget.

Comment: Paste and use the above code ! If any errors, let me know !

Comment: No errors found in your code, but I don't understand how to use snapshot inside the Text Widget, could you explain me? Thank you!

Comment: Create global variable of snapshot where you are using the firebasestreambuilder , and then assign returned snapshot inside the setState method in onDataReceived function